# Directing effects of substituent groups on aromatics

Tags: organic-chemistry

Normally, directing effects of substituent groups on aromatics are explained by drawing resonance structures of the Kekule representation of the compound. My question is that since the Kekule representation is in fact incorrect but rather there is equal electron density in all parts of the pi cloud in benzene, I am not completely satisfied with the explanation which relies on the fact that the bonds are localised.

Is there any other way to explain directing effects of substituents on benzene and other aromatic systems?

Obviously stuff like NMR analysis of phenol proves that the curly arrow predictions of the Kekule structure are true (ortho and para hydrogens have a shift of 6.7 and 6.8 ppm respectively - more shielded than normal benzene hydrogen of 7.2ppm so higher electron density in ortho and para carbons). But that could just be due to chance that the prediction is right. Also how do the curly arrows show that the ortho carbon is very slightly higher in electron density than para?

Comment: The explanation you are talking about explicitly says that the bonds are *not* localised by invoking resonance structures so your argument is somewhat invalid. Molecular orbital theory is the other main way of describing bonding and is probably what you are after but they both produce exactly the same result.